# How to check if user factory is null in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate, rest

I am using spring rest api with hibernate and angularjs and i am fetching data from database using $get() method.

The json object is coming from controller into user factory in angularjs.
Then i am using that user factory in my controller.And if the record doesn't exist in database then i want to set false value in scope.

How can i do this please help me..

Here is my code

```
app.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
UserFactory.get({}, function (userFactory) {
$scope.data = userFactory;
if(userFactory==null){
$scope.data2='true';
}
else{
$scope.data2='false';
}
})
}]);


app.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/SpringRestCrud1/employee/9', {}, {
query: {
method: 'GET',
params: {},
isArray: false
}
})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check like

```
if(!userFactory){
   $scope.data2='true';
}
else{
   $scope.data2='false';
}
```

Comment: not working...if i am sending id which doesn't exist in table then nothing visible on page